# AWS S3 upload failed - the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, ssl, amazon-s3

I have a AWS S3 client configured in my java app. It works fine on my local machine but when deployed to a SSL environment I get an error.

JAVA

```
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Debian-1bpo91)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Debian-1bpo91, mixed mode, sharing)

Spring Boot 2.3.4
```

I use a SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt which I have stored in the running server and configured in Spring boot application.properties:

```
# SSL enabled
server.ssl.enabled=true
# SSL protocol
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
# The format used for the keystore. It could be set to JKS in case it is a JKS file
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.XXXXX.com/keystore.p12
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=XXXXXXX
# The alias mapped to the certificate
server.ssl.key-alias=XXXXXX
```

AWS client config

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);

        s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withRegion(region).withAccelerateModeEnabled(accelaratedModeEnabled)
                .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)
                .build();

        transferManager = TransferManagerBuilder
                .standard()
                .withS3Client(s3Client)
                .build();
```

ERROR:

```
Unable to execute HTTP request: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5219)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5165)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.access$300(AmazonS3Client.java:405)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$PutObjectStrategy.invokeServiceCall(AmazonS3Client.java:6180)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1824)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1784)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInOneChunk(UploadCallable.java:168)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:148)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:115)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:45)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1313)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:408)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy119.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:102)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:181)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:300)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:176)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:189)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:629)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:464)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:360)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:177)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1151)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
        at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
        at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
        at java.base/java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:99)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:181)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:300)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:176)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:189)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:629)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:464)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:360)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:177)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1151)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by simply copying the cacerts file from my local Java VM to the remote environment.

I also make sure the file /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts could be read by the user starting the java process: "sudo chown ci:root /etc/ssl/certs/java/" where ci is the user.